# How to disassemble an obfuscated .NET DLL?

Tags: disassembly, dll, obfuscation, .net, packers

I [asked earlier](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/19938/14864) about unpacking a packed .NET exe. But now I need to see the source code for an obfuscated DLL:

[image]

Any idea how to unpack it?

Comment: did you try https://github.com/de4dot/de4dot

Comment: @SSpoke thanks. Tried it. But unfortunately it gave me `Detected Unknown Obfuscator` and what it created didn't help much.

Comment: well thats the best tool on the market, your last bet is to use (Detect It Easy) https://github.com/horsicq/Detect-It-Easy to figure out which obfuscator it is (if you are lucky idk if it works for .NET programs that well) then use this link: https://github.com/NotPrab/.NET-Deobfuscator together with DIE to narrow it down. On DIE (Try the Nauz File detector) if the default one doesn't find it (for more luck). If DIE doesn't have Nauz try download the stand alone here : https://github.com/horsicq/Nauz-File-Detector

Comment: @SSpoke yeah, it tells me its `Eazfuscator`

Comment: cool I'm pretty sure you already got it done, but ya there is 2 options for that EazFixer / eazdevirt (to run both tools you need to use de4dot first)

Comment: @SSpoke you know, still can't get it. Been following what [this guy does](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScQg_Z98EdA) but no success. I'm not sure what else could be in there?

Comment: Sorry I just linked information from research I never did it myself, so I cannot help haha, but ya that video I just watched seems very reasonable, does it open at all in dnSpy?

Comment: @SSpoke in my case EazFixes fails on StringFixer and then SAE crashes when I tried to do what he did.